# Простая задача по JS

Tags: javascript

Найдите все года от 1 до 2017, сумма цифр которых равна 13.

```
function getDigitsSum(num) {
    var sum = 0;
    var str = String(num);
    for ( i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        sum += Number(str[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

for (i = 0; i <= 2017; i++) {
    if(getDigitsSum(i) == 13) {
        document.write(i + ' ');
    }
}
```

Почему браузер виснет при запуске кода?

Comment: _Почему браузер виснет при запуске кода?_ потому что i - глобальная

Comment: `var i` сделайте, если объявлять переменную без `var` то она станет глобальной. И ещё, научитесь пользоваться отладкой, даже не зная этого, к ответу вы бы быстро пришли сами пройдясь пошагово по коду

Comment: получилось, всем спасибо за ответы!